# Get transparency of a bufferedimage

Tags: java, image, colors, rgb, bufferedimage

I want to change all the blue color of a image. I use this code to chage it.

```
int i, j, red, green, blue;
        for(i = 0; i < 64; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 64; j++){
                Color c = new Color(brImage.getRGB(i, j));
                red = c.getRed();
                green = c.getGreen();
                blue = c.getBlue();
                int rgb = new Color(0, 255, 0).getRGB();
                if(red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 178){
                    brImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is is that it will change color of all the transparent areas as well instead of only the blue areas. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the current pixels alpha level...

```
int i, j, red, green, blue, alpha;
for(i = 0; i < 64; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 64; j++){
        Color c = new Color(brImage.getRGB(i, j));
        red = c.getRed();
        green = c.getGreen();
        blue = c.getBlue();
        alpha = c.getAlpha(); // include me...
        int rgb = new Color(0, 255, 0, alpha).getRGB();
        if(red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 178){
            brImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also try the getTransparency() method 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html